# Convert uint16 bit list to numpy for using opencv imshow

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a  Mono16 camera (1028x1280) that stream the data as a list having datatype uint16, mean size of one image is a list of 2,631,680 numbers, which is actually a pair of 1,315,840 pair of bytes, where the first is LSB and the later is MSB.

How can I take the list and convert it to something that I can stream it live on screen with opencv imshow() function?, I don't want to use only the MSB.

I tried to multiply the MSB by 16 and sum it with the LSB and tham divide by 255 and it is not working because it is to heavy for the computer and I don't get live image.

thank you